# How to render react tab first index active

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render the first index of React tab active on page load, I have set defaultIndex={0}, yet on page load, none of the tabs is render active

```
const saving =  () =>(
       <div className="container">
           <div className="row">
               <div className="col-12">
                   <div className="card">
                       <div className="card-body">
                       <Tabs defaultIndex={0}  onSelect={ index => console.log(index)}>
                            <TabList>
                            { categories && categories.map((cat, i)=>(
                                    <Tab key={i}>{cat.name}</Tab>
                            ))}
                            </TabList>
                            { categories && categories.map((cat, i)=>(
                            <TabPanel key={i}> {cat.name}
                            </TabPanel>  ))}
                           
                       </Tabs>
                       </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the following?:

`<Tabs selectedIndex={0} ... />`

API documentation is available [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs#selectedindex-number)